# TCPDF image bottom alignment inside table

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm trying to align images to the bottom of a td element to achieve something like this (the three images, independently from the height of the other images, will be always on the bottom of the td):

**Expectative:**

[image: TCPDF Image alignment expectative]

With the following markup:

```
    <?php 

    // create some HTML content
    $html = '<h1>Image alignments on HTML table</h1>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="text-align:center;">
        <tr>
            <td width="33%">
                <img src="signature1.png" border="0" align="bottom"/>
            </td> 
            <td width="33%">
                <img src="signature2.png" border="1" align="bottom" style="margin-bottom: 0px;" />
            </td>
            <td width="33%" align="bottom">
                <img src="signature3.png" border="0" align="bottom" style="padding: 5px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    // output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

    //Close and output PDF document
    $pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

However TCPDF doesn't support padding nor margin rules and i'm getting the following result:

**Reality:**

[image: TCPDF Images not aligned to the bottom]

[In the official documentation](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/) there's the align bottom property but it doesn't work.

> Note: it's worth to say that the images don't have transparent pixels
>   around them (on top or bottom where it matters ... ) e.g:

[image: TCPDF Signature no margins]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try ‘float:bottom;’ css property in the img tag and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Pitifully TCPDF ended up without support for padding or margin, which means that what i needed wasn't technically possible. I decided to move [to Dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) that allows this behaviour using CSS rules ([specifically vertical align, mentioned in this article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/686/how-to-align-an-image-to-the-bottom-of-a-table-cell-in-dompdf)).